# How does Affine Transform works in this code?

Tags: java

The following code works correctly, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the details.  Can somebody help me understand how the `AffineTransform` is working to rotate the image?

```
package pks;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class rotate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new rotate();
    }

    public rotate() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

           public void run() {

                final RotationPane rotationPane = new RotationPane(); // initilize object of RotationPane class
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(rotationPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class RotationPane extends JPanel {

        private BufferedImage img;
        private BufferedImage rotated;

        private double angle;

        public RotationPane() {

            try {
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\pardeep\\Desktop\\tomb1.jpg")); // path of the image to be rotated
                setAngle(45);
            } 
            catch (IOException ex) {
            }

        }

        public void setAngle(double angle) {
            this.angle = angle;

            // Using Affine transform we will calculate the new values
            //x=vcos (theta)+wsin(theta)
            //y=vcos(theta)+ wsin(theta)

            double rads = Math.toRadians(angle);  // calculating angle in radian
            double sin = Math.abs(Math.sin(rads)),  //calculating sin theta
                   cos = Math.abs(Math.cos(rads)); // calculating cos theta

            int w = img.getWidth();
            int h = img.getHeight();

            int newWidth = (int) Math.floor(w * cos + h * sin);  //using affine transform
            int newHeight = (int) Math.floor(h * cos + w * sin);

            rotated = new BufferedImage(newWidth, newHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            Graphics2D g2d = rotated.createGraphics(); //rotating planes.....

            AffineTransform plane = new AffineTransform();

            plane.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);

            int x=w/2;
            int y=h/2;

            plane.rotate(Math.toRadians(45), x, y);

            g2d.setTransform(plane);
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
        }


        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return  new Dimension(800,   // setting the window size
                              800);
        }

        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // super.paintComponent(g); no need for it

            if (rotated != null) {   // drawing image on 2 dimentional size surface
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create(); 

                int x = (getWidth() - rotated.getWidth()) / 2;
                int y = (getHeight() - rotated.getHeight()) / 2;

                g2d.drawImage(rotated, x, y, this); // overriding the method......
            }
        }        
    }    
}
```

Comment: http://www.datagenetics.com/blog/august32013/index.html

Comment: Do you know what an [affine transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation) is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly don't you understand? `plane.rotate(Math.toRadians(45), x, y);` rotates the image around the center point clockwise by 45 degrees. `plane.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);` is the same as `plane.translate(newWidth/2 - w/2, newHeight/2 - h/2);` so it calculates the difference between the new center and the old center and moves the entire picture by that difference.

I should mention that AffineTransform applies the transformations in the opposite order.
So if you write this

```
plane.translate((newWidth - w) / 2, (newHeight - h) / 2);
int x=w/2;
int y=h/2;
plane.rotate(Math.toRadians(45), x, y);
```

Then every pixel of of the image is first rotated by 45 degrees clockwise and then shifted, not the other way around. It's done this way because the transformations are supposed to be applied to the coordinate system. Applying transformation A followed by tranformation B to the coordinate system is mathematically equivalent to applying B followed by A to the pixels of the image.

Comment: The paintComponent method draws the image at the center of the JPanel. To do that it calculates the difference between the center of the JPanel and the center of the image to determine where to draw it.

Comment: but it sir it  has already drawn the picture using             g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this); this method....then why we are using this method   g2d.drawImage(rotated, x, y, this); //

Comment: In the setAngle method the image is drawn into another image, not to the screen.